# Change a widget's datasource from client side code

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a situation where I have multiple calculated datasources that can be displayed on ene page. But for some reason I cant seem to change the datasource of the widget on the page.
Is this possible at all? I have tried all combinations but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it is not possible to change widget's datasource in runtime.

There are some exceptions for some widgets... For instance with widgets like Dropdown or Multiselect you can dynamically change their `options`, `values` and `names` properties, but in most cases it works only with simple types(strings/numbers) and strictly saying it is not real datasource change.

There is also dirty hack with `Dynamic` custom property type, but I'll not recommend to use it...

So... if you have multiple datasources for the same Calculated Model, I would consider squeezing all of them into one and adding parameters to tell your server side which records it should return.